# How to disable app support for Android tablet screen from AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android

I'll appreciate any help here - I want to make my Android app be installable **only** on phones as it totally cannot function on tablets. How can I do that?

At the moment, I have these in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="false"
              android:xlargeScreens="false"
  />
```

.
.
.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
```

When I upload the application, Market says that the app supports API versions 3 through 15+ and it can still be found on my Motorola xoom tablet. I have also changed the project build target to 10.

Comment: so what exactly is not gonna run on tablets? So according to you screen is the issue, higher api level will do just fine?

Comment: The app does not look right on tablets at all. In essence, I'm avoiding API levels 11,12 and 13. As for 14 and up, I will only wanna make available the app to the smaller screen devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
android:maxSdkVersion=10
```

CAUTION: If you dont want to work any version above api level 10. This includes normal phones also like Galaxy Nexus which is coming soon. Pls check more [details](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#max)

Well if you want to filter based on screens 'supports-screen' won't gonna work. Here is the [reason](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html#manifest-filters)

**Here is another [soln](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html#advanced-filters)** and you also need to read [compatible screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html).

Comment: Hi @haverxz, thanks for the quick response. I have thought of that but I do not want to miss out on the upcoming phones that support higher API levels. :(

Comment: Hello..I've found that even setting the following does not help. `android:normalScreens="false"`

Comment: Hi @haverxz, it does seem to work with the compatible-screens tag! Thanks!

Comment: be aware that this will not make your app visible for phones with 4.0

Answer (score 3):

Guided by what is written on [dev guides](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps) you shoild configure your manifest like this:"

```
<manifest ... >
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
...
<application ... >
    ...
<application>
```

Comment: Will this work if my app already supports tablet and I don't want the tablets to get an update to a specific version ?