# Stop android app running on tablets

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I want to stop the my android application running on Tablets. I have given like below in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:xlargeScreens="false" 
android:resizeable="false" 
android:largeScreens="false"/>
```

Still app is installing and running on Tablets. **How to prevent this?**

Comment: Same issue i'd also. But, i knew this will work only on uploaded app into market. But, i'm not sure about this.

Comment: @SpK: I have uploaded in AndroidMarket, and tried. But still installing

Comment: What? After uploaded itself also its working? Different one. I don't know about this? Let see your upcoming answer for your question. Am also waiting??

Comment: @SpK: yes issue is exists in uploaded apps also. And If you are having the same issue na, you can give upvote, so that some one may answer faster

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable app support for Android tablet screen from AndroidManifest.xml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454034/how-to-disable-app-support-for-android-tablet-screen-from-androidmanifest-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add <**compatible-screens**> in your AndroidManifest.xml...

see this links...

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/filters.html#advanced-filters

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Comment: This is the right answer. From the first link: _"As a general rule, Google Play assumes that the platform on the device can adapt smaller layouts to larger screens, but cannot adapt larger layouts to smaller screens."_ Using `<compatible-screens>` turns off that assumption.

Comment: This information is very good. But what exact tags need to be used to prevent the app from running on tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454034/how-to-disable-app-support-for-android-tablet-screen-from-androidmanifest-xml). I think it answers your scenrio.

Comment: The answer to that question is flawed. It disables support for API levels above 10, which is not at all the same thing that OP wants.

Comment: ya but it explains we cant restrict an app to only phones by the link given below in the same answer